# Script engine prior to Java SE 6?

Tags: java, java-5, scriptengine

For some reason, I have to use Java 5. I started learning programming from java se 7 so i am not familiar with the old versions.

`javax.script` package, which contains the `ScriptEngine` class and `ScriptEngineManager` class does not exist in Java 5. But Rhino project was created way before Java 5. So I am wondering how to use java script engine before `javax.script` was introduced in java 6?

(I scanned through Java se 5 API documentation. There doesn't seem to be a substitution for `ScriptEngine` class. And all the online searching result gives me the modern code.)

Comment: The tag you're using is wrong - you want "Java ScriptEngine", not "Javascript engine". That's why it was removed.

Comment: In fact, i was looking for a Java ScriptEngine to run JavaScript.

Comment: @Will - not withstanding that, you should use tags that are *most closely* associated what you are asking about.  And that is "java scriptengine" rather than "javascript engine".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to download the source/jars for from the Rhino project and use them directly: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Apache BSF](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bsf/). Rhino actually appears on the [list of supported languages](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bsf/projects.html).